# Merge img and background image

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to insert an image to the background, so it becomes just a background.. For instance, it is the same task as if I merged the background-image of the page with this particular image in the photoshop and then inserted it to the web page as ONE picture. But I am curious if it possible to insert the image through HTML. 
Because I have a problem with the menu on my Web. When I open the menu, the inserted image is not on the background, actually it shows before the background, so my menu is uncklickable because of this..
Thanks.

The code:

```
<ul class="nav_menu">
            <li id="idea_list">
                <a href="@Url.Action("Techniques", "Menu")">
                    Home
                </a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="challenges_list">
                <a href="#">
                    Challenges
                </a>
                <ul>
                    @* jQuery generated items *@
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

And I have an image on the background under this menu with the absolute position that interferr with the menu when it is open.

```
  <img class="menu_pointer" src="~/Content/Images/minified/idea_menu.png">
```

Comment: Please post your code but sounds like a problem with `z-index`

Comment: how could you think someone could give you the exact answer solving the problem when the question is just like a story?

Comment: @KingKing Cmon man, why so angry? Chill, I thought it is just a trivial question for you guys.

Comment: @ShukhratRaimov why do you think I'm so angry? I did not even downvote your question, remember that please, when I'm angry, I will surely downvote the question and even vote close and flag it as low quality.

Comment: @KingKing OK man I will remember it, but I find the 'imbondbaby user' approach speaking to people and asking them to do stuff much nicer:)

Comment: Can you make a fiddle with your images? so please include the full path to the images

Comment: @imbondbaby Sorry, I dont know what fiddle is :( But I have a problem with only one image, the one that is under the menu, that interferr with the <li> stuff when I hover over the "Home" or "Challenges".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just place the image before the nav.

HTML:

```
 <img class="menu_pointer" src="~/Content/Images/minified/idea_menu.png">

<ul class="nav_menu">
            <li id="idea_list">
                <a href="@Url.Action("Techniques", "Menu")">
                    Home
                </a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="challenges_list">
                <a href="#">
                    Challenges
                </a>
                <ul>
                    @* jQuery generated items *@
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  color: yellow;
  background:
    url(http://fc02.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2012/171/7/0/png_cat_by_eross_666-d5459oe.png) no-repeat bottom right,
    url(http://scienceblogs.com/gregladen/files/2012/12/Beautifull-cat-cats-14749885-1600-1200.jpg) no-repeat top left
    ;
  background-size: 70%;
}
```

Comment: No, unfortunatelly it is not solving the problem, the <li> items of menu are still interfere with the image.

Comment: try placing the img tag above the nav, if you dont have to be specific in its position in the document.

Comment: Thanks, @jacelysh. Pls edit your answer, so I can set it as the accepted one.